# Programming an app to show vga-output of another device in app window / c#

Tags: c#, streamreader, vga

I am a c# hobbyist, and I found a new "project", but am not sure where to start. So any hints will be very welcome!

I have digital mixing console with a black/white 7"-display. However, the console is quiet old, and I fear that display is going down soon.

Last year I bought a dedicated add-on card that acts like a signal splitter: the image is transfered to that card and you can connect a VGA cable to the card and see the display image on an external screen. There is also an USB-B port that streams the same signal.

My idea was to write a nice little app with only one purpose: open a single window and show me exactly what I see in the display of the mixer or my external screen (which in either case is always the same image).

So: plugging the card's USB-cable into my PC, and than have an app that con show me the stream/display.

My take on this might perhaps be naive, but that's why I am here. Which path would I have to go? Where are the caveats? Which procedure to follow? I am NOT asking for code, just a kinda roadmap and where to start. Are there any libraries to behold?

For the last years I programmed solely wpf-applications, but I am also familiar with windows forms.
Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: I would try using VLC for that purpose.

Comment: I am familiar with this player, Michael. Though, could you be more specific as to how this could help me? Just as reminder: I want to connect the USB-Video out from the mixer to my Pc, and than have an app that could do the job and show me it's screen. I don't need to re-invent the wheel - if vlc would do, I'd gladly jump on that train. Thanks.

Comment: This should help: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Open_Media/

Comment: Nope - juste tested it; unfortunately, that's not gonna work: it doesn't show USB-devices that send video signals. I don't think it may be video after all, because the mixer screen shows a static image (unless you tweak some inputs like faders and knobs). So, no, this is no solution.